# How to configure the color of the hexagons on the spring-boot-admin wallboard depending on the health Status?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

When i have a spring-boot service that has Status OUT_OF_SERVICE, it is coloured red on the spring-boot-admin wallboard. I would like to give the hexagon a non-red color.
How can i configure the color of the hexagons on the wallboard, depending on the health Status?

The reference guide doesn't specify how to change the color

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, but you can create an enhancement request here: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/new/choose

in general the team is open to add such a feature